# How to do multiple queries from a single table at once and do math calculations?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to get the following result but struggle to query the logic.
What I want is to get the exact number of transactions/invoices after removing the canceled transactions (- negative custnb) from the table. SO with my sample table, I have 5 transactions, 2 are canceled, so I would like to only get the 3.

**WANTED RESULT**

```
Invoices     Customers

3            3
```

---

**TABLE**

```
invoicenumber         custnb     invoiceid

    1001              1          1001
    1002              2          1002
    1003              1          1003
    1004              5          1004
    1005              2          1005
    2000001           -1         1001
    2000002           -2         1002
```

Comment: I can't see any relationship between cancelled and non-cancelled "transactions". (not even after you modified CUSTNB values). What makes a transaction in this table? Does "-1" cancel both 1001 and 1003 invoicenumbers (as well as -2 cancels 1002 and 1005)? How is then invoiceid = 1001 for custnb = -1 related to anything? I think you should fix that example, because - it doesn't make sense. At least, not to me.

Comment: Yes sorry the table is wrong.
Custnb is actually the number of customers(person). This is a manual entry so I could have as high as it can be.
The invoicenumbers starting from 200000 are canceled transactions. And the invoiceid is the reference id. So with the 2000002, this invoice number is the canceled 1002 invoicenumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you put it, this returns desired result; lines #1 - 9 represent sample data, so code you need begins at line #10.

```
SQL> with test (invoicenumber, custnb, invoiceid) as
  2    (select 1001,  1, 1001 from dual union all
  3     select 1002,  2, 1002 from dual union all
  4     select 1003,  1, 1003 from dual union all
  5     select 1004,  5, 1004 from dual union all
  6     select 1005,  2, 1005 from dual union all
  7     select 2001, -1, 1001 from dual union all
  8     select 2002, -2, 1002 from dual
  9    )
 10  select count(invoicenumber) invoices,
 11         count(custnb) customers
 12  from test
 13  where custnb > 0
 14    and invoicenumber not in (select invoiceid
 15                              from test
 16                              where custnb < 0
 17                             )
 18  ;

  INVOICES  CUSTOMERS
---------- ----------
         3          3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but it would be something like this. Also, assumption is a customer may have multiple invoices.

```
select count(t.invoicenumber) invoices, count(distinct t.custnb) customers
from table t
where t.custnb > 0
and not exists (
 select 1 from table t2 
 where t2.invoiceid = t.invoiceid
 and t2.custnb < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to aggregate at the invoice level and then count.  Uncancelled invoices will have a "positive" `custnb`:

```
select count(*) as num_invoices, count(distinct custnb) as num_customers
from (select invoiceid
      from t
      group by invoiceid
      having min(custnb) > 0
     ) t;
```

If the `custnb` and `invoiceid`s line up exactly (as they now do), I would approach this using `not exists`:

```
select count(*) as num_invoices, count(distinct custnb) as num_custoers
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.invoiceid = t.invoiceid and
                        t2.custnb = - t.custnb
                 );
```

Or possibly using `except`:

```
select count(*) as num_invoices, count(distinct custnb)
from ((select invoiceid, custnb
       from t
       where custnb > 0
      ) except
      (select invoiceid, - custnb
       from t
       where custnb < 0
      )
     ) ic
```